# SipSorcery Register and Invite use different ports

Tags: .net, .net-core, sip, voip

I am currently trying make a call with a small WPF application on my windows pc via [SipSorcery](https://github.com/sipsorcery-org/sipsorcery) . I am using .net 6 and latest version of SipSorcery package. During the registration of user agent I don't get any error and I see success response. I assume this part is ok. But when I make a call I get

> 403 Forbidden

error as response. I have no idea what might cause it. But I can see during Registration and Invite the user agent is using different ports. I started to think this might be problem. I try to set same port for Registration and Invite by adding a new Channel to current SipTransport object but it didn't work. It doesn't matter what I set as port number looks like SipSorcery assign different port each time.

My registration request :

[image]

My Invite request :

[image]

this is how I make a call :

```
 public async Task MakeCall()
    {
        // ...
        var sipTransport = new SIPTransport();
        sipTransport.PreferIPv6NameResolution = preferIPv6;
        //sipTransport.AddSIPChannel(new List<SIPChannel> { new SIPTCPChannel(IPAddress.Any, 47063) });
        sipTransport.CreateChannel(SIPProtocolsEnum.udp,AddressFamily.Unknown,47063);

        sipTransport.EnableTraceLogs();

        SIPURI callUri = SIPURI.ParseSIPURI(DEFAULT_DESTINATION_SIP_URI);

        var audioSession = new WindowsAudioEndPoint(new AudioEncoder());
        audioSession.RestrictFormats(x => x.Codec == AudioCodecsEnum.PCMA || x.Codec == AudioCodecsEnum.PCMU);
        var rtpSession = new VoIPMediaSession(audioSession.ToMediaEndPoints());

        var offerSDP = rtpSession.CreateOffer(preferIPv6 ? IPAddress.IPv6Any : IPAddress.Any);

        var uac = new SIPClientUserAgent(sipTransport);

       // Codes for trying and failing ... etc 
       
        SIPCallDescriptor callDescriptor = new SIPCallDescriptor(
                       username: DEFAULT_USERNAME,
                       password: DEFAULT_PASSWORD,
                       uri: callUri.ToString(),
                       from: $"sip:{DEFAULT_USERNAME}@{DEFAULT_SERVER}",
                       to: DEFAULT_DESTINATION_SIP_URI,
                       routeSet: null,
                       customHeaders: new List<string> {
                           "Allow:INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH,MESSAGE"
                            ,"User-Agent:SIP.js/0.14.6"
                       },
                       authUsername: null,
                       callDirection: SIPCallDirection.Out,
                       contentType: SDP.SDP_MIME_CONTENTTYPE,
                       content: offerSDP.ToString(),
                       mangleIPAddress: null);

        uac.Call(callDescriptor, null);

      // ...

    }
```

And this is the registration:

```
    public void RegisterSipUser()
    {
       
        SIPTransport.PreferIPv6NameResolution = true;
        SIPTransport.EnableTraceLogs();

        Log = AddFileLogger(LogEventLevel.Verbose);
        SIPURI sIPURI = new SIPURI(DEFAULT_USERNAME, HOST, null, SIPSchemesEnum.sip, SIPProtocolsEnum.udp);
        SIPEndPoint sIPEndPoint = new SIPEndPoint(sIPURI);

        _userAgent = new SIPRegistrationUserAgent(SIPTransport, sIPEndPoint, sIPURI, DEFAULT_USERNAME, DEFAULT_PASSWORD, "xxx.net", HOST, sIPURI, DEFAULT_EXPIRY,null);

        _userAgent.UserAgent = "SIP.js/0.14.6";
        // Event handlers for the different stages of the registration.
        _userAgent.RegistrationFailed += (uri, err) => Log.LogError($"{uri}: {err}");
        _userAgent.RegistrationTemporaryFailure += (uri, msg) => Log.LogError($"{uri}: {msg}");
        _userAgent.RegistrationRemoved += (uri) => Log.LogWarning($"{uri} registration failed.");
        _userAgent.RegistrationSuccessful += (uri) => Log.LogInformation($"{uri} registration succeeded.");

        _userAgent.Start();

    }
```

Two questions:

- Is having different ports during call and registration  a problem ?
- How can I set a port for both action ?